# How to prevent systemd from stopping service after a failed reload?

Tags: systemd

For my service I configured an `ExecReload=` command similar to this one:

```
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c 'check-configuration && reload-service'
```

This command checks the configuration before doing the actual reload. If this check fails, the service gets not reloaded — which is the wanted behavior.

What's not so nice: Because of the failed `systemctl reload ...` (the `check-configuration` exits with some error code), systemd decides to stop my service.

How can I prevent systemd from stopping my service when the reload command returned a non-success exit code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have hit [systemd bug 11238](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/11238), which is unresolved and currently has no workaround.

You should report this to your Linux distribution's bug tracker, so that they can track the upstream bug and backport any fix that might be created in the future.

Comment: Yep. That's it. Thank you for this hint!
Regarding my distribution: I use Archlinux, so I should get the new version as soon as it is fixed.